# How can i calculate sum of character variable in r

Tags: r, character

IN R

my data

```
a <- c('1','2','3','1','1')
b <- c('3','1','2','1','2')
j <- data.frame(a,b)



rowSums(j)                 #error
```

How can I calculate sum of the row?

Comment: You should be aware of the real classes of the columns in your data. Try `str(j)` and you'll see that they aren't `character` class.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In case you have *real* `character` vectors (not `factor`s like in your example) you can use `data.matrix` in order to convert all the columns to `numeric` class

```
j <- data.frame(a, b, stringsAsFactors = FALSE)
rowSums(data.matrix(j))
## [1] 4 3 5 2 3
```

Otherwise, you will have to convert first to `character` and then to `numeric` in order to not lose information

```
rowSums(sapply(j, function(x) as.numeric(as.character(x))))
## [1] 4 3 5 2 3
```

Comment: @DavidArenburg you rock dude!